# How to write JavaScript function to check JRE version

Tags: java, javascript

I am new to JavaScript. How to write JavaScript function which will return installed Java version in the computer.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the [JNLP, the Sun Unified Deployment Mechanism](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html), the `getJREs()` function is your answer:

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
     var versions = deployJava.getJREs();
     alert(versions);
</script>
```

### NB

it works in a **consistent fashion across various browsers**

Answer (score 4):

```
var JavaVersion = PluginDetect.getVersion('Java', 'getJavaInfo.jar');
var Java0Status = PluginDetect.isMinVersion('Java', '0', 'getJavaInfo.jar');
alert('Java version is ' + JavaVersion + '\n' + 'Java status is ' + Java0Status);
```

This is the **[plugin detect generator page](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/PluginDet%20Generator.htm)**, also you can check **[here](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/JavaDetect.htm)** for detail about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `deployJava.getJREs()` method in the [Deployment System](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) (returns a list of currently installed JREs).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, You cannot directly check Java Version from Javascript, You will need 2 steps.

- Check Java is installed or not with javascript first

  navigator.javaEnabled()
- And then load your java applet, and check it there for version.

PS: **[DeployJava](http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js)** mentioned by others, also doing similar method

Here is some of its codes, writing object tags to page, and checking it.

```
document.write('<'+'object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
document.write('<'+'object classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-DEC7-0000-0000-ABCDEFFEDCBA"
```