# Detect client jre from web browser

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, applet

I want to organize print file operation from my web application. I think that best way - print it from applet. But before run applet, i must install jre to client machine.

Is there any way to detect from web application - is client machine have installed jre?

This feature needs to show some message if jre not available.

I think that answer on my question is "No", but hoping to hear a different answer i write here...

Comment: you can use javascript, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873342/how-to-write-javascript-function-to-check-jre-version

Comment: *"I think that best way - print it from applet."* 

I suspect you are wrong there.  What exactly does an applet add to the functionality over dumping the raw file to the user and allowing them to decide what to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `deployJava.js` as mentioned & linked in the [applet tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).