# How to get the version number of the latest java update available?

Tags: javascript, java

How to determine using javascript if the current installed jre is the latest version.

Thanks so much.

Comment: You're going to want to do this with a server-side language, not javascript

Comment: I would like to do it through javascript because it is executed through client side and check the jre installed of the client. My purpose is when available latest update is not equal to the jre installed, I will redirect to another link, if equal it will redirect to default link/.

Comment: There's not going to be a good way to check the JRE of the client machine.  Any browser that allowed that would be opening a lot of security loopholes.

Comment: Java already provides a functions which is deployJava.js but the one of the functionalities is to get only the jre installed on the PC but It doesn't have a function check the availble updates version number.

Comment: Try using an applet. Its going to be real hard finding the *currently installed* version otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on SO yielded half of the answers your looking for.

[Get the JRE version using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873342/how-to-write-javascript-function-to-check-jre-version)

To be able to get version number for available updates is going to be tricky. I couldn't find anything out there that already does this. I imagine that if you do come up with a way to do this, it would have to be cross browser compatible unless of course your able to do this using a Java applet.

Comment: Please provide context for your link; link-only answers are frowned upon.