# Detect java version using deployJava.js ,pops up java upgrade menu

Tags: java, javascript, deployjava

I have a need to know the java version installed on client machine, have come up with the solution here

[How to write JavaScript function to check JRE version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873342/how-to-write-javascript-function-to-check-jre-version)

When I tried, got with the answer:

```
console.log(deployJava.getJREs());
```

But at the address bar,  pop up menu is displayed like this

[image]

How to hide this?.

If this can not be achieved, please suggest any other idea to implement, as this can not be used,if this popup is not suppressed

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure from recent experiments that there is no way to suppress it.  For the script to detect the plug-in versions, it must invoke the plug-in itself.

---

After those experiments I worked to create a script that could detect a variety of things out about the Java plug-in without invoking the plug-in itself.  They relied on examining the mime-types info.

This still shows a warning in IE *if opened from the local file-system.*  But I *hope* it will be more forgiving if loaded from the internet.  Please report back.

But note this is what it reports for IE when the 'allow scripts' check is OK'd.

[image: IE Information of on Java]

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Java Information - Non Deployment Toolkit Script</title>
<meta name='author' content='Andrew Thompson'>
<meta name='description' content='Non Deployment Toolkit Script'>
<script src='mimetypes.js'></script>
<style type='text/css'>
.true {
    background-color: #6F6;
}
.false {
    background-color: #FB0;
}
.undefined {
    background-color: #FF0;
}
.datum {
    font-family: monospace;
}

td {
    padding: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Java on this PC</h1>

<h2>Overview</h2>
<p>This page endeavors to ascertain the installation, availability
&amp; version of the Java installed on the client PC.
More importantly, it attempts to discover the information <b>without
invoking the Java Plug-In</b> itself.
The last part is what makes it different
to the Deployment Toolkit Script supplied by Oracle.
</p>

<script type='text/javascript'>

document.write("<h2>Browser Info.</h2>");
document.write(getBrowserInfo());


document.write("<h2>Basic Info.</h2>");
document.write("<table border='1'>");

document.write(get3CellRow('<b>Enabled</b>', isJava(), 'Java is enabled (1.1+) - IE info. (short of ActiveX) stops here'));
document.write(get3CellRow('<b>Version</b>', getVersion(), 'Maximum version reliably <em>known</em> to be available'));
if (isIE()) {
    document.write(get3CellRow('<b>MSIE</b>', getIEVersion(), 'Maximum version reliably known to be available in IE, tested using ActiveX'));
}
document.write(get3CellRow('<b>JWS</b>', isJWS(), 'Java Web Start available (1.4.2+)'));
document.write(get3CellRow('<b>Plug-In 2</b>', isPlugin2(), 'Plug-In 2 available (1.6.0_10+)'));

document.write("</table>");

if (plugins.length>0) {
    document.write("<h2>Navigator Plug-Ins</h2>");
    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    document.write("<tr><th>Name</th><th>Version</th><th>File Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>");
    for (var ii=0; ii<plugins.length; ii++) {
        var t = plugins[ii].name;
        if (t.indexOf("Java")>-1) {
            document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<td>" + plugins[ii].name + "</td>");
            document.write(getDataStyledCell(plugins[ii].version));
            document.write("<td>" + plugins[ii].filename + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + plugins[ii].description + "</td>");
            document.write("</tr>");
        }
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}

if (mimes.length>0) {
    document.write("<h2>Navigator Mime-Types</h2>");
    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    document.write("<tr><th>Mime</th><th>Description</th><th>Types</th></tr>");
    for (var ii=0; ii<mimes.length; ii++) {
        var t = mimes[ii].type;
        if (t.indexOf("java")>0 &&
            ((t.indexOf("jpi")>0 || t.indexOf("deploy")>0 || t.indexOf("jnlp")>0 || t.indexOf("vm")>0) ||
            mimes[ii].description.length>0)
            ) {
            document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<td>" + mimes[ii].type + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + mimes[ii].description + "</td>");
            document.write("<td>" + mimes[ii].suffixes + "</td>");
            document.write("</tr>");
        }
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}
</script>

<hr>

<h2>Description</h2>
<p>In order (if available) the information is:

<ul>
<li><b>Browser info. Table:</b>  Not strictly related to Java - the
information in the other tables is determined without
further reference to any information shown in this table (except for the <code>appName</code> used for
identifying IE).
OTOH it is an helpful guide
as to what we should be <em>expecting</em>
from the other information. E.G.  IE
will not show the Plug-In or Mime Type tables.  <em>Only</em>
FF displays the plug-in version numbers.
</li>
<li><b>Basic info. Table</b>
    <ul>
    <li><b>Enabled</b>:  Java is known to this browser and enabled, according to JavaScript <code>navigator.javaEnabled()</code>.</li>
    <li><b>Version</b>:  The maximum Java version known to be supported in this browser/PC.
    It is set to <code>1.1</code> if the previous check is <code>true</code>, since the MSVM
    was the first Java version the public could get in a browser, and the MSVM
    implemented Java 1.1.  Goes on to check
    <code>application/x-java-applet;jpi-version</code>
    in the mime types if available
    (i.e. typically browsers that are <em>not</em> IE).
    </li>
    <li><b>MSIE</b> (IE Only):  The maximum Java version known to be supported by this instance of Internet Explorer
    as determined using ActiveX.  It runs from 1.4.2, 1.5.0.. through 1.9.0.
    </li>
    <li><b>JWS</b>:
    Inferred from a comparison of the version to the Sun JRE in which
    it was co-bundled.</li>
    <li><b>Plug-In 2</b>:
    Inferred from a comparison of the version to the Sun JRE in which
    it was introduced.</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><b>Navigator Object Tables:</b>
    <em>The rest of the info. is gleaned from the <code>navigator</code> object.
    IE does not include this information.</em>
    <ul>
    <li><b>Plug-Ins</b>: More details of the Java related plugins.
    Filtered for <code>Java</code> in the <code>name</code>.
    A <code>description</code> showing "Next Generation Java Plug-in" or <code>name</code>
    "Java Deployment Toolkit" should be 1.6.0_10+.</li>
    <li><b>Mime-Types</b>: More information on the Java related Mime-Types.
    Filtered in <code>mime</code> field for <code>'java'</code> + <code>('jpi'||'vm'||'deploy')</code>
    or a non-empty <code>description</code>.
    The value <code>java-deployment-toolkit</code> in the <code>mime</code>
    is a good indicator of 1.6.0_10+.
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

### mimetypes.js

```javascript
// As a version string, this might be '1.4.2_31'.  
// I.E. it is not a 'number' but a 'string' and therefore must be treated as a string.
var highestVersion = 'undefined';

var mimes = window.navigator.mimeTypes;
var plugins = window.navigator.plugins; 

function isJava() {
    return (
        typeof(navigator.javaEnabled) !== 'undefined' &&
        navigator.javaEnabled());
}

function getVersion() {
    var version = 0;
    if (isJava()) {
        version = 1.1;
    }
    for (var ii=0; ii<mimes.length; ii++) {
        var t = mimes[ii].type;
        if (t.indexOf("java")>0 &&
            t.indexOf("jpi")>0 &&
            t.indexOf("applet")>0
            ) {
            var parts = t.split("=");
            version = parts[parts.length-1];
        }
    }
    if (highestVersion=='undefined') highestVersion = version;
    return version;
}

function isJWS() {
    var ver = highestVersion;
    var className = false;
    if (ver>'1.0') {
        className = undefined;
    }
    if (ver>'1.4.2') {
        className = true;
    }
    return className;
}

function isPlugin2() {
    var ver = highestVersion;
    var className = false;
    if (ver>'1.0') {
        className = undefined;
    }
    if (ver>'1.6.0_10') {
        className = true;
    }
    return className;
}

var versionFamily = [
    '1.9.0', '1.8.0', '1.7.0',
    '1.6.0', '1.5.0', '1.4.2'
];

function getIEVersion() {
    for (var i=0; i<versionFamily.length; i++) {
        if  (testUsingActiveX(versionFamily[i])) {
            return versionFamily[i];
        }
    }   
    return false;
}

if (isIE() && getVersion()=='1.1') {
    highestVersion = getIEVersion();
}

function isIE() {
    return navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer';
}

function testUsingActiveX(version) {
    var objectName = 'JavaWebStart.isInstalled.' + version + '.0';

    // we need the typeof check here for this to run on FF/Chrome
    // the check needs to be in place here - cannot even pass ActiveXObject
    // as arg to another function
    if (typeof ActiveXObject == 'undefined' || !ActiveXObject) {
        alert('[testUsingActiveX()] Browser claims to be IE, but no ActiveXObject object?');
        return false;
    }

    try {
        return (new ActiveXObject(objectName) != null);
    } catch (exception) {
        return false;
    }
}

function get3CellRow(cell1, cell2, cell3) {
    var s = "" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<td class='" +
        getClassName(cell1) +
        "'>" +
        cell1 +
        "</td>" +
        getDataStyledCell(cell2) +
        "<td class='" +
        getClassName(cell3) +
        "'>" +
        cell3 +
        "</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "";

    return s;
}

function getDataStyledCell(value) {
    var s = "<td class='datum " +
        getClassName(value) +
        "'>" +
        value +
        "</td>";

    return s;
}

function getClassName(val) {
    var className = undefined;

    if (
        (val) ||
        (!val) ||
        (val!=="undefined")
        ) {
        className = val;
    }

    return className;
}

function getBrowserInfo() {
    var s = "";

    var props = [
        'appCodeName','appName','appVersion',
        'userAgent',
        'platform','cookieEnabled'
    ];

    s += "<table border='1'>";
    for (var i=0; i<props.length; i++) {
        s+= "<tr>";
        s+= "<td><b>";
        s+= props[i];
        s+= "</b></td>";
        s+= "<td>";
        s+= navigator[props[i]];
        s+= "</td>";
        s+= "</tr>";
    }
    s += "</table>";

    return s;
}
```

Please note (be warned) this script was written by me, a Java programmer.  Java programmers are typically the *absolute worst people on the planet* for writing JS, since we foolishly tend to presume.  "It's JavaScript, how hard can it be?".

To write really **good** JavaScript is indeed an art.

Even worse, this was experimental code that was 'hacked out' with the intention of improving it later, but the project was abandoned and 'later' never arrived.

Caveat emptor.

Comment: hey dude this looks great, but in IE the details are not displaying.

Comment: Yes, I noted your original question mentioned IE specifically, but then it was quickly removed.  IE is one of the most difficult browsers to determine such information, given it does *not* support the mime-types object supported in just about every other browser.  Had you seen the edit where I included a screenshot?  My only thought for IE at the time (I wanted to completely factor out the deployJava script) was to then 'bite the bullet' and insert a Java 1.1 compatible applet to do the rest of the checking, but that would of course invoke the very same warnings.  Sorry, but I think..

Comment: ..the conclusion we can reach is 'No can do', at least not for IE.